# angularjs: change filter options dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I want is something like [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) example in the documentation but with a unique input that can play the three roles of filtering by "any", "name" or "phone" properties, the change of role is done by an anchor click.
Here is the code ready http://jsfiddle.net/ubugnu/QuyCU/ How can I update the ng-model attribute dynamically?

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

      <label>Any</label> <input type="text" ng-model="search.$"> <br>
      <label>Name only</label> <input type="text" ng-model="search.name"><br>
      <label>Phone only</label> <input type="text" ng-model="search.phone"><br>

      <div style="background-color:#FAE8F1">
      <hr>

      <label>Filter</label> <input type="text" ng-model="search.$"> by {{filter}} <br>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="changeFilterTo('$')">Any</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="changeFilterTo('name')">By Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="changeFilterTo('phone')">By phone</a></li>
      </ul>

      <hr>
      </div>

      <table class="table">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search">
          <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
          <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                      {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                      {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                      {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                      {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'}];
    $scope.filter = "$";
    $scope.changeFilterTo = function(pr) {
        $scope.filter = pr; 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can define `ng-model` like: `ng-model="search[filter]"` to change dynamically to which variable it should be binded (where `filter` is another `$scope` variable).

See the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/lopisan/vzQKk/1/

You have to add this line to the controller:

```
$scope.search = {name:'', phone:'', $:''};
```

And change input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search[filter]">
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, in the fiddle...try searching for 'a' and clicking 'phone'. It appears to be searching on 'All' regardless of the link clicked. I think it only needs a small tweak or two to work, though.

Comment: I think it works ok, but maybe in a little bit non-intuitive way (but it demonstrate the solution nicely) - when you click "Any|By Name|By phone", it just links bottom textbox to one of corresponding upper textboxes. So typing 'a' fills the 'a' to "Any" and clicking 'by phone' switches bottom textbox to "phone" so next typing add phone constraints leaving "any" constrain alone..

Comment: Is there any way to have filter by "name" and "Phone" ONLY

Comment: Very clever solution!

Answer (score 8):

Here's one approach - there are probably others.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div style="background-color:#FAE8F1">
      <hr>

      <label>Filter</label> <input type="text" ng-model="multi"> by {{filter}}         <br>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="changeFilterTo('$')">Any</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="changeFilterTo('name')">By Name</a></li>
      <li><a href="" ng-click="changeFilterTo('phone')">By phone</a></li>
      </ul>

      <hr>
      </div>

      <table class="table">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:getFilter()">
          <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
          <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                      {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                      {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                      {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                      {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'}];
    $scope.filter = "$";
    $scope.multi = "";
    $scope.changeFilterTo = function(pr) {
        $scope.filter = pr; 
    }
    $scope.getFilter = function() {
        switch ($scope.filter) {
            case 'name':
                return {name: $scope.multi};
            case 'phone':
                return {phone: $scope.multi};
            default:
                return {$: $scope.multi}
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another simple approach using radio buttons

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search[filter]">

<label>filter by these</label>

<label>Any <input type="radio" ng-model="filter" ng-init="filter = '$'" value="$"></label>
<label>name<input type="radio" ng-model="filter" value="name"></label>
<label>phone<input type="radio" ng-model="filter" value="phone"></label>
```