# Set search mode dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new at angularjs so be patient ^^
I'm playing around with angularjs.
How can I set the search mode dinamically ?
I've tried with this code with no luck :(

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Binding</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-app="myApp">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="{{mysearch}}" />
            <select data-ng-model="mysearch">
                <option value="search.$">All</option>
                <option value="search.name">Name</option>
                <option value="search.email">Email</option>
            </select>
            <span>{{mysearch}}</span>
            <div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">  
                <table>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="actor in rows.cast | filter:search">
                        <td>{{actor.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{actor.email}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp',[]);
       myAppModule.factory('Avengers',function(){
           var Avengers = {};
           Avengers.cast = [{name:'joe',email:'joe@mysite.com'},{name:'david',email:'david@mysite.com'},{name:'charles',email:'charles3@mysite.com'}]
           return Avengers;
       });
       function MyCtrl($scope,Avengers){
          $scope.rows = Avengers;
       } 

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by search mode?  I'm assuming it means that you want to set the value you are filtering on based on a variable?

Comment: search.$ search.name search.email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AngularJS Tutorials</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/4.3.1/css/foundation.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="AvengersCtrl">
            <select ng-model="mysearch" ng-change="change()">
            <option value="$">All</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="character">Character</option>
        </select>
            <input type="text" ng-model="search[filter]">
            <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="actor in avengers.cast | filter:search">
                    <td>{{ actor.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ actor.character }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.factory('Avengers', function () {
        var Avengers = {};
        Avengers.cast = [
            {name: 'Fabio',character: 'superman'},
            {name: 'whisher',character: 'spiderman'}
        ];
        return Avengers;
    });
    function AvengersCtrl($scope, Avengers) {
        $scope.filter = "name";
        $scope.search = {name:'', character:'', $:''};
        $scope.avengers = Avengers;
        $scope.change = function(){
            $scope.filter = $scope.mysearch;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

many thanks to @lopisan [angularjs: change filter options dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319645/angularjs-change-filter-options-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

The docs say this:

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)

> Parameters array – {Array} – The source array. expression –
>   {string|Object|function()} – The predicate to be used for selecting
>   items from array. Can be one of: string: Predicate that results in a
>   substring match using the value of expression string. All strings or
>   objects with string properties in array that contain this string will
>   be returned. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with
>   !.
>
> Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on
>   objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"}
>   predicate will return an array of items which have property name
>   containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property
>   name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any
>   property of the object. That's equivalent to the simple substring
>   match with a string as described above.
>
> function: A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters.
>   The function is called for each element of array. The final result is
>   an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for.

You should maybe have 2 input fields, one for name and one for email, then pass in an object to the filter that corresponds to the fields in your data model, name and email.

You can also write custom filters, they are actually pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, all in all I want to set the search mode (search.$ search.name search.email) by the select