# AngularJs grouping by property

Tags: angularjs

I need a way to order a list by its properties.

I have this plunker: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/aF2aL/1/

but don't know hoe to proceed. I need a way to order the list based on what I select in checkboxes...

```
function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.friends = [

    {
        name: "Michael",
        gender: "Male",
        hair: "Brunette"
    },
    {
        name: "George Michael",
        gender: "Male",
        hair: "Brunette"
    },
    {
        name: "Gob",
        gender: "Male",
        hair: "Brunette"
    },
    {
        name: "Tobias",
        gender: "Male",
        hair: "Black"
    },
    {
        name: "Lindsay",
        gender: "Female",
        hair: "Blonde"
    },
    {
        name: "Maeby",
        gender: "Female",
        hair: "Black"
    }
];
$scope.orderBy = function(target){
    $scope.groups = _.groupBy($scope.friends, target);
}
$scope.activeGroups = {};
```

}

And this is my html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="orderBy('name')" />Name
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="orderBy('gender')" />Gender
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="orderBy('hair')" />Hair

<div data-ng-repeat="(myFilter, users) in groups">
    <h2>{{myFilter}}</h2>        
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="user in users">
        {{ user.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how about if you check 2 checkboxes?

Comment: Try to use $watch on the group types and set `groups` accordingly.

Comment: Could you explain with some example? I'm a noob...

Comment: Hi, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17617664/set-search-mode-dynamically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-repeat conditional wrap items in element (group items in ng-repeat)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493063/angular-ng-repeat-conditional-wrap-items-in-element-group-items-in-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, for something like this, I much prefer using a `radio` instead of a `checkbox`.  It is semantically correct.  Check boxes indicate that you can group by more than one field, and it doesn't appear, from your question, that you are trying to do that.

Knowing that, you can define your radios like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="grouping" value="name"  />Name
<input type="radio" ng-model="grouping" value="gender" />Gender
<input type="radio" ng-model="grouping" value="hair" />Hair
```

Now, you can just tell your `ng-repeat` to group based on a `groupedFriends` collection:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="(group, users) in groupedFriends">
    <h2>{{group}}</h2>        
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="user in users">
            {{ user.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then your controller just watches the `grouping` variable and group the data:

```
$scope.$watch('grouping', function() {
    $scope.groupedFriends = _.groupBy($scope.friends, $scope.grouping);
});

$scope.grouping = "gender";
```

Here is a [working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aF2aL/17/)

STEVE HOLT!

Comment: That isin't an acceptable answer. If you notice in the console, you will see that it's causing infinite digests.

Comment: @plalx Good point.  I can fix this.  I'll try to get that up.  Thanks!

Comment: The only way I managed to fix it in my application was to perform the grouping in the controller and expose a `groupedItems` property on the `$scope`. I am not sure it's the best or only way however. You can put a watch on `friends` to make sure the groupings are updated when `friends` changes.

Comment: @plalx Yeah, I've updated it.  Using a function to return a different array every time causes the `$digest` to fire over and over again.  The better way to do it (and no more code than before) is to watch the `grouping` property and group the data into a new property.

Comment: Kudos for the Arrested Dev ref.

Comment: I tested it and i want to know how to hide empty or inexistant key and value like this example with no name: {gender: "Female",hair: "Black"} It show a empty <li>

Answer (score 3):

You can use groupBy of [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module, It's easy to use, and actually more fast  than lodash implementation see: [link](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter/wiki/Performance,-angular-filter-vs.-lodash-filter).
**Usage:** `(key, val) in collection | groupBy: 'property'` or `nested.property`
here's an example:

**JS:**

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
  Group name: {{ key }}
  <li ng-repeat="player in value">
    player: {{ player.name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

**RESULT:**
  Group name: alpha
    * player: Gene
  Group name: beta
    * player: George
    * player: Paula
  Group name: gamma
    * player: Steve
    * player: Scruath

**UPDATE:** [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/weyov/45/edit?html,js,output)