# Angular ng-repeat conditional wrap items in element (group items in ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to group the items in a ng-repeat using a condition.

An example condition is to group all elements with the same hour.

The data:

```
[
    {name: 'AAA', time: '12:05'},
    {name: 'BBB', time: '12:10'},
    {name: 'CCC', time: '13:20'},
    {name: 'DDD', time: '13:30'},
    {name: 'EEE', time: '13:40'},
    ...
]
```

The 'time' field is actually a timestamp (1399372207) but with the exact time the example output is easier to understand.

I am listing these items using ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="r in data| orderBy:sort:direction">
   <p>{{r.name}}</p>
</div>
```

also tried with:

```
<div ng-repeat-start="r in data| orderBy:sort:direction"></div>
    <p>{{r.name}}</p>
<div ng-repeat-end></div>
```

A valid output is:

```
<div class="group-class">
    <div><p>AAA</p></div>
    <div><p>BBB</p></div>
</div>
<div class="group-class">
    <div><p>CCC</p></div>
    <div><p>DDD</p></div>
    <div><p>EEE</p></div>
</div>
```

My last option if there isn't a simple solution for my problem would be to group the data and then assign it to the scope variable used in ng-repeat.

Any thoughts?

Comment: we can create our own data set for these

Comment: Your output is different form normal

Comment: An *on-the-fly-groupBy* filter (or controller-method) of any sort is rather hard to implement in angular, because angular will not recognize the grouped array/object to be *unchanged* and thus run into the dreaded *Infinite $digest Loop*. Your best bet is to implement some sort of stable grouping using `$watch`. It's ugly but probably the only way at the moment.

Comment: Are you dealing with a defined number of groupings or dynamic based on the data?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use groupBy filter of [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module.
so you can do something like this:

**usage:** `collection | groupBy:property`
use nested property with dot notation: `property.nested_property`
**JS:**

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
  Group name: {{ key }}
  <li ng-repeat="player in value">
    player: {{ player.name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

**RESULT:**
  Group name: alpha
    * player: Gene
  Group name: beta
    * player: George
    * player: Paula
  Group name: gamma
    * player: Steve
    * player: Scruath

**UPDATE:** [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/weyov/45/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This works fine but error in console : `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] `, How to solve it?

Comment: @HirenKagrana, which version you use ?
try to use version 0.4.7 from cdnjs, it's old issue that been solved

Comment: I found `sum` filter useful together with `groupBy` in standard table with total scenarios.  See http://plnkr.co/edit/PlC93j?p=preview for an example built upon @HireKagrana one.

Comment: What if I have an array with three values and I want to print Color next to the Group Name?   $scope.players = [
      {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha', color:'green'},
      {name: 'George', team: 'beta', color: 'white'},
      {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma', color:'blue'},
      {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta', color:'white'
      },
      {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma', color:'reded'}
    ];

Comment: what if I need to show the team rank with the team name?

Comment: Don't know if you've had the opportunity to play with Angular 2/4, yet; however, it looks like they've removed the `groupBy` clause, which is curious.

Answer (score 19):

First make group in Controller:

```
 $scope.getGroups = function () {
    var groupArray = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (item, idx) {
        if (groupArray.indexOf(parseInt(item.time)) == -1) {
            groupArray.push(parseInt(item.time));
        }
    });
    return groupArray.sort();
};
```

Then Make a Filter for it:

```
 myApp.filter('groupby', function(){
    return function(items,group){       
       return items.filter(function(element, index, array) {
        return parseInt(element.time)==group;
       });        
    }        
 }) ;
```

Then Change Template:

```
 <div ng-repeat='group in getGroups()'>
     <div ng-repeat="r in data | groupby:group" class="group-class">
         <div><p>{{r.name}}</p></div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kQM7m/)

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't require a module

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple **HTML** solution for static groups.

```html
<ul>
  Group name: Football
  <li ng-repeat="player in players" ng-if="player.group == 'football'">
    Player Name: {{ player.name }} 
  </li>
  Group name: Basketball
  <li ng-repeat="player in players" ng-if="player.group == 'basketball'">
    Player Name: {{ player.name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Output:**

Group name: Football
 - Player Name: Nikodem
 - Player Name: Lambert
Group name: Basketball
- Player Name: John
- Player Name: Izaäk
- Player Name: Dionisia

Comment: This solution won't work if the `$index` of the repeated item is needed to reference the item in the `players` collection...