# How to do table formatting in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I generated table data and table columns dynamically in angularjs. My table is

```
Name    Hobby
XXXX    Music
XXXX    Cricket
XXXX    Books
YYYY    Tennis
YYYY    Books
YYYY    Drawing
```

But I want my table to be displayed like this :

```
Name    Hobby

XXXX
        Music
        Cricket
        Books
YYYY
        Tennis
        Books
        Drawing
```

I used the following code to generate table :

```
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="th in keys">{{th}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in data ">
            <td ng-repeat="th in keys">
                {{ x[th]}}
            </td>
         </tr>
```

My json looks like this

```
[{"Name:"XXXX", "Hobby":"Music"},
{"Name:"XXXX", "Hobby":"Cricket"},
{"Name:"XXXX", "Hobby":"Books"},
{"Name:"YYYY", "Hobby":"Tennis"},
{"Name:"YYYY", "Hobby":"Books"},
{"Name:"YYYY", "Hobby":"Drawing"}]
```

I can't use similar to this

```
<ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
```

because my table headers are created dynamically

How I can do this in angularjs?

Comment: we need to see your JSON data

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493063/angular-ng-repeat-conditional-wrap-items-in-element-group-items-in-ng-repeat

Comment: Manipulate Your data accordingly as you want to show it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this thing on markup itself, no need of sorting or filtering an array.

**Markup**

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="th in keys">{{th}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
        <td ng-repeat="th in keys">
          <span ng-show="th != 'Name' || (th == 'Name' && data[$parent.$index - 1]['Name'] != x['Name'])">
          {{ x[th]}}
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jgZveYWxW95iGrPN8xj0?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

here is simple javascript solution:

```
var array = [{"Name":"XXXX", "Hobby":"Music"},
{"Name":"XXXX", "Hobby":"Cricket"},
{"Name":"XXXX", "Hobby":"Books"},
{"Name":"YYYY", "Hobby":"Tennis"},
{"Name":"YYYY", "Hobby":"Books"},
{"Name":"YYYY", "Hobby":"Drawing"}];

 var distinctNames = []

 for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
   if(distinctNames.indexOf(array[i].Name) === -1){
      distinctNames.push(array[i].Name);
   }
   else{
       array[i].Name = "";
   }
 }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mmqzfvja/)

After this filter you can render array in your table

Answer (score 0):

I would use [**ng-table**](http://ng-table.com/)
You will be able to easily sort, filter and group your table.