# "ng-group" feature exists on ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Using non-3rd party plugins:

I have an array like this:

```
[
    {groupName:'General', label:'Automatic Updates', type:'select', values:{0:'On', 1:'Off'}},
    {groupName:'General', label:'Restore Defaults', type:'button', values:['Restore']},
    {groupName:'General', label:'Export & Import', type:'button', values:['Export', 'Import']},
    {groupName:'Timing', label:'Double Click Speed', type:'text'},
    {groupName:'Timing', label:'Hold Duration', type:'text'}
]
```

I want to ng-repeat over this but create groups.

The final result I'm hoping will look like this:

[image]

So basically that is a `ng-repeat` on the `groupName` to make two `div` containers, then it `ng-repeat`s for each item within to add the rows.

Is this possible without having to change my array into an object like this:

```
[
   'General': [...],
   'Timing': [...]
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular ng-repeat conditional wrap items in element (group items in ng-repeat)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493063/angular-ng-repeat-conditional-wrap-items-in-element-group-items-in-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like this, one solution is to split up the repeat into 2 separate repeats. the easiest is to do that by creating a small helper filet that filters out the unique properties. a filter like this would do:

```
function uniqueFilter() {
    return function(arr,property) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call( arr ) !== '[object Array]') {
            return arr;
        }
        if (typeof property !=='string') {
            throw new Error('need a property to check for')
        }
        return Object.keys(arr.reduce(isUn,{}));

        function isUn(obj,item) {
            obj[item[property]] = true;
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

That filter will return an array that consist of the unique  values of the property you want to group by.

Once you have this you can nest a couple of ngRepeats like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in vm.data| uniqueFilter:'groupName'">
    {{group}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in vm.data| filter:{groupName:group}">{{item.label}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And you should be set.
There is no need to pull in a 3rth party for this.
see it in action [in this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/gEhStGCANsq3o4iXiNZK?p=preview).

Comment: It's been working great and I'm trying to study it, it keeps throwing this even though it works: `Error: arr is undefined` does it do the same for you? Here is my js: https://github.com/Noitidart/MouseControl-v2.0-temp/blob/master/resources/scripts/ng-prefs.js#L130-L143 and here is my ng-repeat its a directive in a directive: https://github.com/Noitidart/MouseControl-v2.0-temp/blob/master/ng-prefs.xhtml#L22

Comment: Oh this where I use it in the directive: https://github.com/Noitidart/MouseControl-v2.0-temp/blob/master/resources/directives/configWrap.htm#L3 i cant figure out why it says arr is undefined but works :(

Comment: Ah the issue was my variable is undefined on intiail load, and it gets defined later on, so when its undefined how can we make it fail gracefully? Should I `throw` in the filter?\

Comment: Ah I made it: `if (arr === undeifned) { return }` it seems to fail gracefuly now, meaning no message in error console :) Was this correct move? Thanks for this awesome teaching!

Comment: Ah, yes, it needs an array to work. Forgot to put in that check. I will adapt the sample and the plunk now.

Comment: Oh shoot @Sander I found another issue with this. I just found it and am trying to figure out whats up. If we add an item where the string of `group` appears as a substring (case insensitive) in any of the other group names, it gets duplicated, please see plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/G8z62LBrM432LzaDowRC?p=preview and here is screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/xPhavbg.png there should only be one item in the `T` and `RAL` groups but the items form the `Timing` and `General` groups are getting duplicated into it.

Comment: Makes sense, T is part of their groupname, so they show, that's how filter works. When you check the docs, you will see that there is a 3rth parameter. If you add :true to your filter it will work.

Comment: Ahhhh I see thanks!!! `item in vm.data| filter:{groupName:group}:true` fixed it :D