# Split ng-repeat based on object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `ng-repeat` on an array of objects similar to this:

```
var objects = [
  {
    name: 'test',
    id: 1234,
    category: 'a'
  },
  {
    name: 'sample',
    id: 4567,
    category: 'b'
  },
  {
    name: 'example',
    id: 7890,
    category: 'a'
  }, ...
];

<p ng-repeat="object in objects">{{object.name}}<p>
```

This array contains over a dozen objects with 4 distinct categories. What I want to do is split these objects up in my UI to display each under its category heading:

Category: a
  test
  example
Category: b
  sample

Is there any way to accomplish this with one `ng-repeat`? My current thinking is that I'll need to split this up in to four identical `ng-repeat`s based on data that I 'categorize' separately in my controller. Just hoping there was a DRYer way to accomplish this.

Comment: Plz add `ng-repeat` template to question, and yes it can be done

Comment: @vinayakj Updated with an example of the very basic `ng-repeat` I'm currently working with.

Comment: Please go through this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493063/angular-ng-repeat-conditional-wrap-items-in-element-group-items-in-ng-repeat

Comment: @MattDionis Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 2):

[Working PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/vnE7kxkAaMbnSEKw8pnk?p=preview)

To solve this problem, I'm using two Angular 'filters', [OrderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), which receives a property of an object an sorts that object based on that. The second is the ['Filter filter'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), which receives an array, do some operation and send it back. I'm using your object as $scope.things.

Markup:

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="thing in things | orderBy: 'category' | thingsFilter">
      <p>{{thing}} </p>
    </div>

    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>
```

First, I'm using the orderBy, which will order by array based on the things.category property. Then, with the ordered array, I'm applying an Angular custom filter.

app.js

```
app.filter('thingsFilter', function () {
  return function (things) {
    var filtered = []; //Return array.
    for (var i=0; i< things.length; i++ ){ //Iterate over things.
      if (i > 0 ) { //To make sure I won't compare with things[-1]
        if ((things[i].category) != (things[i-1].category)) {
          //If category of last item is different, add the name of category.
          filtered.push("_____CATEGORY: " + things[i].category + ":");
        }
      } else { //Insert the first category.
        filtered.push("_____CATEGORY: " + things[i].category + ":");
      };
      console.log(things[i]); //Just to see what is happening.
      filtered.push(things[i].name); //Inserting the name of the thing.
    };
    console.log(filtered); //The final array to
    return filtered;       //be returned here.
  };
});
```

The input of the filter is the things object, which has been ordered by the orderBy. So, I have an ORDERED array. Now, I had created the filtered variable, which will hold all the value to be sent back.

Next, I'm lookin to see if the variable i is greater than zero, so I won't compare with a negative index and bug my code. If the index is zero, then I will add a category line.

Since the array is ordered, I can check if the category of the last array is different than the actual one. If it is, then I will add the category in the array with filtered.push("____CATEGORY...").

At the end of each for loop, I will push the things[i].name to the array to be returned. And, at the end, I will return the filtered array, so my ng-repeat can use it.

[Working PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/vnE7kxkAaMbnSEKw8pnk?p=preview)