# Angular Ng-repeat grouped

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to show a list using ng-repeat but I couldn't figure out how to group it. This is my json:

```
 {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Andre Nascimento",
  "client": "Lojas Mais"
},
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Andre Nascimento",
  "client": "Fe comercio"
},
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Andre Nascimento",
  "client": "Transtour"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Carla Prata",
  "client": "Fe comercio"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Carla Prata",
  "client": "Transtour"
}
```

I would like to getthe follow result

```
Andre Nascimento 
  *Lojas Mais
  *Fe comercio
  *Transtour

Carla Prata
  *Fe comercio
  *Transtour
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25342374/2157370) answer. Then you would have something like

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in yourArray| groupBy: 'client'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
        <li ng-repeat="element in value">
            player: {{ element.name }} 
        </li>
</ul>
```

this should do it.
[here there is a fiddle](http://jsbin.com/budiluxohe/edit?html,js,output)