# ng-repeat that skips duplicate properties

Tags: angularjs, duplicates, expression, angularjs-ng-repeat, repeat

I want to do an ng-repeat over an array, skipping certain properties when they are duplicates of a previous iteration.

### Model ("events" array)

```
[
   {
   "id": "event1",
   "date": "June 1st"
   },
   {
   "id": "event2",
   "date": "June 2nd"
   },
   {
   "id": "event3",
   "date": "June 2nd"
   },
   {
   "id": "event4",
   "date": "June 3rd"
   }
]
```

As you can see the date is duplicated for `event2` and `event3`...

### HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events">  
  <h2>{{event.date}}</h2>
  <p>{{event.id}}</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

So the desired result is:

---

**June 1st**
event1

---

**June 2nd**
event2
event3

---

**June 3rd**
event4

---

My guess is it is something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events">  
  <h2 ng-if="<!--expression here-->">{{event.date}}</h2>
  <p>{{event.id}}</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Would it be a function in my controller attached to a variable called in the ng-if attribute?

And primarily, how would I form that expression to do what I want in this case?

**Note: It is ONLY the rendering of the *date* variable I want to avoid, not the entire ng-repeat element.**

Any help, or alternative suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to use something like `group by` on the date variable. Please see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493063/angular-ng-repeat-conditional-wrap-items-in-element-group-items-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make ng-repeat filter out duplicate results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914658/how-to-make-ng-repeat-filter-out-duplicate-results)

Comment: Saad - that looks like a decent solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom filter to filter out the unique items:

```
app.filter('uniq', function() {
    return function(items, param) {
        var filteredItems = [];
        items.forEach(function(item) {
            var found = filteredItems.some(function(elem) {
                return elem.param === item.param;
            });
            if(!found) {
                filteredItems.push(item);   
            }
        });
        return filteredItems; 
    }
});
```

Use it like this:

```
event in events | uniq: 'date'
```