# Advanced Search with filter - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, radio-button

I'm trying to create a advanced search with a specific filter.
Currently when using the filter option, everything gets searched, but I want to have it more specific.

I want to create a dropdown that gives you the option to search through the names or places instead of searching through all the results:

```
<form class="input-group col-md-4 form-inline">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search captures" ng-model="search"/>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Options <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><input type="radio"  name="searchoption" value="All" id="All" checked><label for="all">Search through all</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="searchoption" value="Birdname" id="Birdname"><label for="birdname">Search by birdname</label></li>
      <li><input type="radio" name="searchoption" value="Place" id="Place"><label for="place">Search by place</label></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </span></button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Depending on the selected radiobutton, I want the `filter.search` to change:

```
<li ng-repeat="capture in captures|filter:search:strict|orderBy:'created_at':true|startFrom:currentPage:10" class="masonry-item clickable">
```

So basicly I want the user to be able to select a specific radio button, and depending on what he picks, it'll search a specific result.

In the Angular documentation it states that my ng-model on my search input has to be one of the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search captures" ng-model="search.$>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search captures" ng-model="search.birdname">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search captures" ng-model="search.place">
```

Though is there a specific way I can change those, depending on the radio button checked?

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few changes:

- Change `ng-model` for *input* to `search[searchBy]`

  ```
  <input type="text" ng-model="search[searchBy]">
  ```
- Set same `ng-model` equals to `searchBy` for all *radio* buttons and set the `value` as per search by condition like `$` for all, `birdName` to search in `birdName` property of the object that is stored in `captures` that you are trying to filter out.

  ```
  <li><input type="radio" name="searchoption" ng-model="searchBy" value="$" id="All" checked><label
      for="all">Search through all</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="searchoption" ng-model="searchBy" value="birdName" id="Birdname"><label
      for="birdname">Search by birdname</label></li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="searchoption" ng-model="searchBy" value="place" id="Place"><label
      for="place">Search by place</label></li>
  ```
- last change in `ng-repeat` to filter out based on `searchBy` value set by above radio buttons in `search`

  ```
  <li ng-repeat="capture in captures|filter:search">...</li>
  ```

---

Set initial value in controller for `searchBy` equal to `$` to search in all properties of the object on initial page load that can be changed by selecting different properties from drop down.

For more example please have a look at existing post [angularjs: change filter options dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319645/angularjs-change-filter-options-dynamically)

[Fiddle example mentioned in above post](http://jsfiddle.net/lopisan/vzQKk/1/)

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, though for some reason, the following: ```<input type="radio" name="searchoption" value="$" id="Any" ng-model="searchBy" ng-click="changeFilterTo('$')" checked><label for="all">Search by Any</label>``` isn't checked by default. Would you know why?

Comment: @CedricBongaerts  I have already mentioned it my post. You have to set the default value of `searchBy` in controller `$scope.searchBy='$'` or use `ng-init="searchBy='$'"` in html itself.

Comment: My bad.. Thanks for all the help!